# Setting curl's cookie file manually

Tags: php, cookies

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.example.com    TRUE    /   FALSE   0   session 4029916%2C2010-04-30T22%3A51%3A52%2C1243925043100000000000000000000000000000
```

I'm getting cookies back from an API request, and I need to use those cookies for the following request, how can I set the cookies retrieved from the request to the cookie file that curl uses?

Above you can see an example, I need to write 3 cookies to this file with a different domain.

How can this be done?

Comment: curl does that for you. Just pass the parameters. Shows your code otherwise it is not clear what you've tried so far and what is missing. Also what is so hard to find this via the search on this site?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 2 parameters to the `cURL` request

```
$cookie_file = "/directory/to/cookie1.txt";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
```

`cookie1.txt` has to writable by cURL. Leave the rest to cURL, it will know to put multiple domains and use them.

Comment: Yes, but I want to write to cookie1.txt each time, in the same format that is generated by CURL